# How to identify well known / commonly used encoding mechanisms from a string?

Tags: encoding, jwt, base64, decoding

Imagine I have a string (that is apparently not readable) and I want to find out how this string has been encoded. Is there a a way to identify the encoding mechanism?

For example this string is a JSON Web Token using HS384.

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzM4NCJ9.eyJIZWxsbyI6IldvcmxkIn0.mRpW9xLmful56DNJOAA1gkWsYLvom5xIcpAcUqgt8f2o8LHaH9aD39__LdwVJBTD
```

This string seems to be a simple URL encoded string, assumed by the % within:

```
foobar%C3%96%C3%96
```

This one could be encoded using Base64 because of the tailing =

```
aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=
```

I know that there's not always a safe way to make sure what encoder is used, it may be based on assumptions. But it would be at least helpful to know a way to just run a string to "all known" encoders to see the final result.

Comment: *a JSON Web Token using HS384.* - HS384 is the signature algorithm, that has nothing to do with the encoding. These are actually 3 base64url encoded strings, concatenated with dots, no matter what signature algorithm is used. Generally, it's hard to tell, which encoding exactly was used. It's easier to say which one has not been used. And `aGVsbG8h` is also valid base64. Not every base64 string ends with "=".

Comment: @jps - thanks for your comment. I understand. But it should be at least not too difficult to just "brute force" decoding to a given string and either return multiple results and/or even check the results for plausibility (a results that contains more "strange" UTF characters may be not a "result" compared to a result with 90% of ANSI chars. Simple example: "Hello!"  decoded with Bae64 clearly results in a not readable char.

Comment: you can certainly try different encodings, but your plausibility check assumes that you should find readable text after decoding. Let's look at the signature part of the JWT that you have in your question: `mRpW9xLmful56DNJOAA1gkWsYLvom5xIcpAcUqgt8f2o8LHaH9aD39__LdwVJBTD`.  It's base64url encoded and decoded to `V~y3I8�5E`蛜HrR-փ-$`. What would be the result of your plausibility check? The thing is, more often than not you'll find binary data after decoding base64 or hex encoded strings. Hard to judge the result in such cases.

Comment: `base64.b64decode( 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzM4NCJ9.eyJIZWxsbyI6IldvcmxkIn0='. encode()).decode()` returns (in Python) `'{"alg":"HS384"}{"Hello":"World"}'`